# Quartz job integrated in Spring does not refresh Hibernate Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

I'm using **Hibernate** and **Spring** (in mode *OpenSessionInView*) in a webapp.

I've introduced **Quartz** for scheduling Job for checks.
To be able to inject beans into the Job I make use of the following approach: https://gist.github.com/jelies/5085593

A job in my app is like:

```
@Service
public class SampleJob implements Job {
  @Autowired
  private SampleBusiness sampleBusiness;

  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    for(Student student : sampleBusiness.getStudents()) {
      System.out.println(student.getName());
    }
  }    
}
```

When the webapp starts, and at the first execution of the Job the result is:

- Tom
- Bruce
- Steven

The result is ok.

After that I change in the webapp the name of "Tom" in "Tommy".

On the next execution of the Job the result is:

- Tom
- Bruce
- Steven

Why Hibernate session holds the old data?

I think I have to attach to the Job an Interceptor like I do for my other beans, but I'm not able to attach it to the Job.

Thanks

Comment: what is the difference of time between the two successive executions of jobs and does data gets modified in db

Comment: for example: the job is executed at 10:00 a.m. and next execution will be at 10:05 a.m. I change the name of Student at 10:03 am.

Comment: does this change reflect in the db

Comment: Yes in the DB the name of Student at 10:03 is Tommy (instead of "Tom").

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for the above mentioned situation might be the cache oh the hibernate.

Hibernate uses two levels of caching, level 1 caching and level 2 caching. 
The level 1 caching caches the data that is read frequently, but in case data is not present in hibernate cache it then looks for the same in the level 2 cache.

If the data is present in the cache level2, then it returns the data, if the data is not present here also it then actually hits the database to retrieve the data.

You should try to clear the cache data before hitting the same method.

Although whenever you update a record from the cached data, this data is re-cached. but in case you are trying to update data from other thread or session, it might not get reflected in the first thread, as the data is already present in the level 1 cache of this session.

I hope this drives you to the right direction.